# How to dump results of for loop into a .txt file using Python?

Tags: python

I am working with this python script. I want it to dump all hosts which are alive into a text file and discard all hosts which don't respond to the ping. Currently I have this part.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import subprocess
import sys

ip = "10.11.1."

for sub in range (0,255):
    sweep = subprocess.Popen("ping -c 1 "+ ip+str(sub), shell=True, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = sweep.stderr.read(1)
    sys.stdout.write(out)
```

How would I add the part dumping relevant information into a .txt file?

Answer (score 0):

Saving content to a file 101:

```
with open(<path>, 'w') as f:
    f.write(<content>)
```

Note: the second argument in `open` denotes that we open the file to write. If you want to append the file you would have to use the mode 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to send output to a file?

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for sub in range (0,255):
        sweep = subprocess.Popen("ping -c 1 "+ ip+str(sub), shell=True, 
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        outfile.write(sweep.stderr.read(1))
```

Comment: This is producing the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pingsweep.py", line 12, in <module>
    outfile.write(sweep.stderr.read(1))
IOError: File not open for writing

Comment: you didn't open it for writting, did you put the 'w' thing ?

Comment: I put 'w'. I did run it again and now it works, but writes nothing into a file.

Comment: Hahaha change 'myfile.txt' for an absolute path to the file you want to run, I think python chooses current working directory as your base directory.
In essence myfile.txt --> /home/you/<your favourite directory>/<your favourite file name>